# Finding lengths of a string in an ArrayList using ArrayList as a return value of a method

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LengthsOfStrings 
{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        list.length();
        return lengthList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Ciao");
        list.add("Moi");
        list.add("Benvenuto!");
        list.add("badger badger badger badger");
        ArrayList<Integer> lengths = lengths(list);

        System.out.println("The lengths of the Strings: " + lengths);
    }
}
```

I was thinking something like this, but I don't know what to fill in the `list.length();` with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lengthList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String s : list)
            lengthList.add(s.length());
        return lengthList;
}
```

Comment: One question more, why dont u need to add the brackets after the for each loop?

Comment: Loops don't require brackets if they only have a single instruction, but it is a good practice to always use them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lengths` method should iterate over the input array, and for each `String` in it, add that `String`'s length (which you get by calling `length()` method of `String`) to the output array.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8:

```
public static List<Integer> lengths(List<String> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .map(String::length)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Eran, and in case you want it in short:

```html
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            lengthList.add(i, list.get(i).length());
```